# How to build Python 3.4.3 source code with pygame to exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, pygame

Hello how do i build python 3.4.3 source codes with the Pygame library to an exe file (stand-alone) ? (py2exe, doesn't work.) any suggestions? Thank You

Comment: I recommend to give a more detailed explanation of your problem. How does your project structure look like? How do you use py2exe? Are there any error messages?

Comment: I have 3 classes which broke into files and i import them. When i use py2exe, it does not build the class i imported. So when i run the exe files it crashed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you include them? How does your setup for py2exe look like? Please provide your source to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to your comment it seems that you have a problem with your setup. You have to tell py2exe what to include.

There is a useful explanation how to get a standalone exe and how to manage includes: http://pythontips.com/2014/03/03/using-py2exe-the-right-way/

The overall example in this site looks like follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

DATA=[('imageformats',['C:\\Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/plugins/imageformats/qjpeg4.dll',
'C:\\Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/plugins/imageformats/qgif4.dll',
'C:\\Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/plugins/imageformats/qico4.dll',
'C:\\Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/plugins/imageformats/qmng4.dll',
'C:\\Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/plugins/imageformats/qsvg4.dll',
'C:\\Python27/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/plugins/imageformats/qtiff4.dll'
])]

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True,"includes":["sip"]}},
    windows = [{'script': "main.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
    data_files = DATA,
)
```

and you have to call

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

to get your standalone exe.